# How do I add a local env variable to a container as an env variable?

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer

Consider the following devcontainers.json:

```
{
    "name": "Node.js & TypeScript",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:1-20-bullseye",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1": {
            "installTools": true,
            "version": "latest"
        }
    },
    "containerEnv": {
        "MY_VAR": "foo"
    }
}
```

I need to pass in an existing env variable into the dev container as an env variable. Using a string literal works just fine:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/typescript-node $ printenv MY_VAR
foo
```

I haven't found the right syntax to resolve a local variable from Windows 10/11 into a container though.

I've tried a few combinations of

```
"remoteEnv" | "containerEnv": {
    "MY_VAR": "${localEnv:GITHUB_PAT}"
}
```

to no avail. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Am I correct to assume you're on Windows? (More UNIXy systems only have one kind of environment variable; there's no "local" vs "global" distinction).

Comment: Yes you are correct. I should have made that clearer in text (or just bold) - but the info is hidden in the question.